# Using the output of str.replace as a key to a dictionary

Tags: python

I have an issue in PyGame. When I try to add an obstacle to the video game I try to develop (thanks to this wonderful FreeCodeCamp tutorial: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/create-a-platformer-game-with-python/ ) an error started to appear.
This is the error message:

```
/home/sobuhasy/PycharmProjects/SuperPythonBros/venv/bin/python /home/sobuhasy/PycharmProjects/SuperPythonBros/main.py
pygame 2.3.0 (SDL 2.24.2, Python 3.10.6)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sobuhasy/PycharmProjects/SuperPythonBros/main.py", line 293, in <module>
    main(window)
  File "/home/sobuhasy/PycharmProjects/SuperPythonBros/main.py", line 257, in main
    fire = Fire(100, HEIGHT - block_size - 64, 16, 32)
  File "/home/sobuhasy/PycharmProjects/SuperPythonBros/main.py", line 160, in __init__
    self.fire = load_sprite_sheets("Traps", "Fire", width, height)
  File "/home/sobuhasy/PycharmProjects/SuperPythonBros/main.py", line 41, in load_sprite_sheets
    all_sprites[image.replace(".png"), ""] = sprites
TypeError: replace expected at least 2 arguments, got 1

Process finished with exit code 1
```

And here's the code that is supposed to work (parts of it, full code is at https://github.com/sobuhasy/SuperPythonBros :

```
[...]
class Fire(Object):
    ANIMATION_DELAY = 3

    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        super().__init__(x, y, width, height, "fire")
        self.fire = load_sprite_sheets("Traps", "Fire", width, height)
        self.image = self.fire["off"][0]
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.image)
        self.animation_count = 0
        self.animation_name = "off"

    def on(self):
        self.animation_name = "on"

    def off(self):
        self.animation_name = "off"

    def loop(self):
        sprites = self.fire[self.animation_name]
        sprite_index = (self.animation_count //
                        self.ANIMATION_DELAY) % len(sprites)
        self.image = sprites[sprite_index]
        self.animation_count += 1

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=(self.rect.x, self.rect.y))
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.image)

        if self.animation_count // self.ANIMATION_DELAY > len(sprites):
            self.animation_count = 0
[...]

def main(window):
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    background, bg_image = get_background("Blue.png")

    block_size = 96

    player = Player(100, 100, 50, 50)
    fire = Fire(100, HEIGHT - block_size - 64, 16, 32)
    fire.on()
    floor = [Block(i * block_size, HEIGHT - block_size, block_size)
             for i in range(-WIDTH // block_size, (WIDTH * 2) // block_size)]
    objects = [*floor, Block(0, HEIGHT - block_size * 2, block_size),
               Block(block_size * 3, HEIGHT - block_size * 4, block_size), fire]

    offset_x = 0
    scroll_area_width = 200

    run = True
    while run:
        clock.tick(FPS)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
                break

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE and player.jump_count < 2:
                    player.jump()

        player.loop(FPS)
        handle_move(player, objects)
        draw(window, background, bg_image, player, objects, offset_x)

        if((player.rect.right - offset_x >= WIDTH - scroll_area_width and player.x_vel > 0) or \
                (player.rect.left - offset_x <= scroll_area_width) and player.x_vel < 0):
            offset_x += player.x_vel

    pygame.quit()
    quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(window)
```

I expected an obstacle (a fire trap) to appear in the game just like this:
[what was shown in the FreeCodeCamp tutorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWly4.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
    all_sprites[image.replace(".png"), ""] = sprites
TypeError: replace expected at least 2 arguments, got 1
```

Do not get worried when you see an error message, instead just read it step by step and search on the internet all the words that you don't know.

- [`TypeError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#TypeError) ... This exception may be raised by user code to indicate that an attempted operation on an object is not supported, and is not meant to be ...
- `replace` this is the function that are trying to use in the line above.
- `expected at least 2 arguments, got 1` an argument is a variable that you put inside the parenthesis of a function.

From this we can understand that the error is a simple typo:

```
all_sprites[image.replace(".png"), ""] = sprites
```

Should be:

```
all_sprites[image.replace(".png", "")] = sprites
```

So that now replace has two arguments as it should.

Comment: @SobuHasy You are welcome! Remember to approach all the error messages that you get step by step, starting from the end of the traceback (as it is the most important part). Enjoy!